# Assign first value from ENUM to Ticket Submit method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to assigne first value from `ENUM` when user submit ticket.
I have

```
 public enum TicketStatus
    {
        Otvoren = 1,
        NaCekanju = 2,
        Zatvoren = 3
    }
```

And when user submit ticket is shoul by default submit `Open (Otvoren) = 1` as default value.

**UPDATE**

Here is my TicketContoller with Upsert method (Insert and Edit) ticket which contain `HTTP GET` and `HTTP Post` method

**TicketContoller.cs**

```
 public IActionResult Upsert(int? Id)
        {

            TicketVM ticketVM = new TicketVM()
            {
                Ticket = new Ticket(),
                TicketTypeList = _unitOfwork.TicketType.GetAll().Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.Name,
                    Value = i.Id.ToString()
                })
            };

            if (Id == null)
            {
                return View(ticketVM);
            }

            ticketVM.Ticket = _unitOfwork.Ticket.Get(Id.GetValueOrDefault());

            if (ticketVM.Ticket == null)
            {
                NotFound();
            }
            return View(ticketVM);
        }


[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Upsert(TicketVM ticketVM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (ticketVM.Ticket.Id == 0)
                {
                    _unitOfwork.Ticket.Add(ticketVM.Ticket);
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    _unitOfwork.Ticket.Update(ticketVM.Ticket);
                }
                _unitOfwork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(ticketVM);
        }
```

**Ticket Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace VmSTicketing.Models
{
    public class Ticket
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Opis")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme slanja")]
        public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        [Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme zavrsetka")]
        public DateTime Answered { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Vrsta tiketa")]
        public int TicketTypeID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TicketTypeID")]
        public virtual TicketType TicketType { get; set; }

        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public Client Client { get; set; }

        public int? UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
     

    }

}
```

I am not sure did I made correct my model since ENUM is separate from Model and inside this I add only one class TicketStatus.cs which you can check belowe.

Comment: `var ticketStatus = TicketStatus.Otvoren;`?

Comment: Just a second. Let me edit post first and add more code from controller

Comment: I do not see you enum used in the code?

Comment: I didnt include. Sorry. I have no idea where to include. Contoller or Model  ? TicketStatus is in separete folder call it ENUM and inside this folder I create class TicketStatus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a class you can simply put a default value in it :

```
    public class Ticket
    {
        public TicketStatus Status { get; set; } = TicketStatus.Otvoren;
    }
```

Comment: Hmm TIcketStatus class is separete from my model Ticket and I put TicketStatus in ENUM folder

Comment: You create an enum but it seems it's never used anywhere in the code you show?

Comment: Yes, I never used it. Since I need list of ticket status i put in separete folder

Comment: But I guess your ticket are supposed to have a status? So shouldn't you have a property like the one I show? It does not matter if the enum definition is in a separate file/folder.

Comment: Yes, it should have property TicketStatus

Comment: I add in my TIcket.cs model something like this 
 `public Enum.TicketStatus TicketStatus = Enum.TicketStatus.Otvoren;` 
Correct me If I am wrong

Comment: You should use a property with getter/setter like the rest of your code but this is the idea. So now if no value are provided "TicketStatus.Otvoren" will be the default value.

Comment: But keep in mind if someone send a value (whether you want it or not) the value sent will overwrite the default default.

Comment: Only Admin can chenge this status not user. So after user submit ticket, only user can change this status according to ticket status

Comment: I have one problem right now. I get in IndexPage as Status 0.